# Javamail API working in mobile data but not working in Wifi on android

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I am working on a project which have to send a mail pragmatically. I was able to send the mail using mobile data without any issue,but it is not worked with wifi connection. how to resolve this issue?

here is my code for sending mail:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.user", gmailId);
props.put("mail.smtp.password", password); 
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");


Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp"); 
transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", gmailId , password); //<--exception in this line
transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
transport.close();

Exception: Java mail: Could not connect to SMTP host: …, port: …, java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
```

Comment: Most likely a firewall problem.  See the JavaMail FAQ for [tips on debugging connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While logged in to your gmail account, from which you want to send the emails, go to https://g.co/allowaccess and then press activate.

Good luck :)